# How can I see the topics in LDA topicmodelling in word format using spark in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, lda, topic-modeling, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to create a LDA model using Apache Spark ML in Java. The input documents are in String format. I get the topics in number format but not in word format.

Found a similar question, but sadly the solution is in R- 
[LDA with topicmodels, how can I see which topics different documents belong to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875493/lda-with-topicmodels-how-can-i-see-which-topics-different-documents-belong-to) But I am looking for solutions using the ML lib of Spark in Java.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use CountVectorizer transformer in your pipeline you can recuperate the indexed vocabulary in this way:

```
String[] vocabulary= countVectorizerModel.vocabulary();
```

Then, you run LDA over the SparseVectors that you obtain from that text > (term counts) transformation.

When looking at LDA results,

```
Tuple2<int[], double[]>[] topicsDescribed = ldaModel.describeTopics();

int idxTopic = 0;
for (Tuple2<int[], double[]> element : topicsDescribed) {

    idxTopic++;
    int[] termIndices = element._1;
    double[] termScores = element._2;

    System.out.println("Topic >> " + idxTopic);
    for (int i = 0; i < termIndices.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("termIndex --> " + termIndices[i] + + "word="+ vocabulary[termIndices[i]] +  + ",score= " + termScores[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This works because you keep consistent the vocabulary of terms throughout the pipeline, such as

```
ldaModel.vocabSize() == vocabulary.length
```