# LDA with topicmodels, I am seeing which topic a word belongs to, but not the topic a document belongs to

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I am running a topic model using 48K documents, each very short, between 2 and 15 words per document. This results in 485K words.
Running the model, I found that 19 topics are the best fit.
I want to know which topic a document belongs to.

I ran what was described on a prior question [LDA with topicmodels, how can I see which topics different documents belong to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875493/lda-with-topicmodels-how-can-i-see-which-topics-different-documents-belong-to)

Instead of getting the topic my documents belong to, I am getting the topic that each word belongs to.

What am I doing wrong, and how can get the topic each of the 48K documents belong to?

```
# Identifying the number of topics that best fit the data
myV2dataUS <- read.csv("C:/Users/nbareis/Documents/Final_MergeUS_MLV2_2010.csv", sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8")
colnames(myV2dataUS) <- c("doc_id", "text")
corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(myV2dataUS))
processedCorpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
View(myV2dataUS)
minimumFrequency <- 10
DTM <- DocumentTermMatrix(processedCorpus, control = list (bounds = list(global = c(minimumFrequency, Inf))))
dim(DTM)
sel_idx <- slam::row_sums(DTM) > 0
DTM <- DTM[sel_idx, ]
myV2dataUS <- myV2dataUS[sel_idx, ]
#New syntax
control_LDA_Gibbs <- list(alpha = 50000, estimate.beta = TRUE, verbose = 0, prefix = tempfile(), save = 0, keep = 0, seed = as.integer(Sys.time()), nstart=1, best = TRUE, delta = 0.1, iter = 2000, burnin = 0, thin = 2000)
result <- ldatuning::FindTopicsNumber(
  DTM,
  topics = seq(from = 2, to = 20, by = 1),
  metrics = c("CaoJuan2009", "Deveaud2014"),
  method = "Gibbs",
  control = list(seed = 77),
  verbose = TRUE
)
FindTopicsNumber_plot(result)

# Running the topic model with the best fitting number of topics
K <- 19
set.seed(9161)
topicModelv2 <- LDA(DTM, K, method="Gibbs", control=list(iter = 500, verbose = 25))
tmResult <- posterior(topicModelv2)
attributes(tmResult)
nTerms(DTM)
beta <- tmResult$terms
dim(beta)
rowSums(beta)
nDocs(DTM)
theta <- tmResult$topics
dim(theta)
rowSums(theta)[1:40]
terms(topicModel, 10)

#Identifying which topic a document belongs to
gammaDF <- as.data.frame(topicModelv2@gamma) 
names(gammaDF) <- c(1:19)
toptopics <- as.data.frame(cbind(document = row.names(gammaDF), 
                                 topic = apply(gammaDF,1,function(x) names(gammaDF)[which(x==max(x))])))
```

I ran what was described on a prior question [LDA with topicmodels, how can I see which topics different documents belong to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875493/lda-with-topicmodels-how-can-i-see-which-topics-different-documents-belong-to)

Instead of getting the topic my documents belong to, I am getting the topic that each word belongs to.